# Set PR to autocomplete using Azure DevOps rest API

Tags: azure-devops, azure-powershell, pull-request, azure-devops-rest-api, azure-pipelines-yaml

I am setting up the PR(created manualy by the users) to autocmoplete using rest api from azure pipeline getting following error, kindly help to resolve the issue. details are bleow

**Error**:

> Invoke-RestMethod:
> /home/vsts/work/_temp/57dec5bf-46fb-449d-9fd7-86e123fc352e.ps1:50
> Line | 50 |  … eteResult = Invoke-RestMethod -Method PATCH -Headers
> $headers -Body $ … |
> ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
> | {"$id":"1","innerException":null,"message":"Invalid argument |
> value.\r\nParameter name: Invalid pull request auto complete set by
> id. | Valid values are either the current user identity id, or an
> empty guid | (to unset auto |
> complete).","typeName":"Microsoft.TeamFoundation.SourceControl.WebServer.InvalidArgumentValueException,
> Microsoft.TeamFoundation.SourceControl.WebServer","typeKey":"InvalidArgumentValueException","errorCode":0,"eventId":0}
>
> ##[error]PowerShell exited with code '1'.

**yaml file** :

```
steps:
- task: PowerShell@2
  inputs:
  targetType: 'inline'
  script: |
  \# construct base URLs
  $apisUrl = "$($env:SYSTEM_TEAMFOUNDATIONCOLLECTIONURI)$($env:SYSTEM_TEAMPROJECT)/\_apis"
  $projectUrl = "$apisUrl/git/repositories/XXXXX"
  Write-Output "Print out content of projectUrl $projectUrl"

        # create common headers
        $headers = @{}
        $headers.Add("Authorization", "Bearer $env:SYSTEM_ACCESSTOKEN")
        $headers.Add("Content-Type", "application/json")
      
        $baseUrl = "https://dev.azure.com/XXXXX/XXXXXX/_apis/git/pullrequests/XXXX?api-version=6.0"
        Write-Output "Print out content of baseUrl $baseUrl"
      
        $pullRequestJsonStr = Invoke-RestMethod -Uri $baseUrl -Headers $headers -Method GET 
        Write-Output "Print out content of pullRequestJsonStr $pullRequestJsonStr"
        $pullRequestObj = ConvertTo-Json $pullRequestJsonStr -Depth 5
        Write-Output "pullRequestJsonStr to object $pullRequestObj"
      
        #Write-Output "Print out content of Build.Respository.ID $(Build.Repository.ID)"
      
        $autoCompleteSetId = $pullRequestJsonStr.createdBy.id
        Write-Output "*****Print out content of autoCompleteSetId $autoCompleteSetId"
          
        #Auto complete call
        $setAutoComplete = @{
          "autoCompleteSetBy" = @{
            "id" = $autoCompleteSetId
          }
          # "completionOptions" = @{       
          #   "deleteSourceBranch" = $False
          #   "bypassPolicy" = $False
          # }
        }
        try {
          $setAutoCompleteJson = ($setAutoComplete | ConvertTo-Json -Depth 5)
        } catch {
          Write-Host "Unable to create json due to $_"
        }
        Write-Output "Print out content of setAutoCompleteJson  $setAutoCompleteJson"
      
        Write-Output "***Sending a REST call to set auto-complete on pull request***"
        
        # REST call to set auto-complete on Pull Request
        # if ($autoCompleteSetId -ne $null) {
          $pullRequestUpdateUrl = ($projectUrl + '/pullRequests/' + $pullRequestJsonStr.pullRequestId + '?api-version=6.0')
          Write-Output "Print out content of pullRequestUpdateUrl $pullRequestUpdateUrl"
      
          $setAutoCompleteResult = Invoke-RestMethod -Method PATCH -Headers $headers -Body $setAutoCompleteJson -Uri $pullRequestUpdateUrl
          Write-Output "Pull request set to auto-complete"
        # }
        # else {
        #   Write-Output "Pull request already set to auto-complete"
        # }

  env:
  SYSTEM_ACCESSTOKEN: $(System.AccessToken)
  displayName: 'PowerShell Script'
```